# Excluir coleções firebase firestore

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-database, firestore

tenho N coleções criadas em meu Cloud Firestore, e gostaria de excluir todas se possível, como se fosse zerar meu banco pois foram inseridas de forma errada. Gostaria de saber se existe como excluir em lote, mais de uma coleção por vez no firestore.

Answer (score 2):

clicando nos três pontos da coleção  você consegue excluir a coleção com tudo o que tem dentro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

tenho uma aplicação em angular com angularfire. criei está forma de apagar a coleção:

```
deleteCollection(path: string, batchSize: number): Observable<any> {
    const source = this.deleteBatch(path, batchSize);
    return source.pipe(
      expand(val => this.deleteBatch(path, batchSize)),
      takeWhile(val => val > 0)
    );
  }

  /**
   * Em teste!
   * Apaga toda uma coleção.
   */
  private deleteBatch(path: string, batchSize: number): Observable<any> {
    const colRef = this.afs.collection(path, ref =>
      ref.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize)
    );
    return colRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      take(1),
      mergeMap((snapshot: any) => {
        const batch = this.afs.firestore.batch();
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          batch.delete(doc.payload.doc.ref);
        });
        return fromPromise(batch.commit()).pipe(map(() => snapshot.length));
      })
    );
  }
```